# WCF WebSocket, Get stream to send and received data

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, websocket, .net-4.5

I am currently getting started with websockets. I have good experience with WCF and want to try out using websockets via WCF if possible.

When hosting standard web resources using WCF it is possible to get a stream to return data and I am hoping to be ablte to do the same with WCF and websockets, so that I can have an input stream to read data from the client and an output stream to return data.

This is my code so far:

```
var netHttpBinding = new NetHttpBinding();
netHttpBinding.WebSocketSettings.TransportUsage = System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebSocketTransportUsage.Always;
webSocketTestHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(WsTest));
webSocketTestHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWsTest), netHttpBinding, "http://localhost/WsTest");
webSocketTestHost.Open();
```

For the IWsInterface I have no clue on where to begin. Maybe something like this?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWsTest {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Ws")]
    void Ws(Stream s);
}

class WsTest : IWsTest {
    public void Ws(Stream s) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int len = s.Read(buffer, 0, 100);
        s.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

However does not seem to work. Maybe it is impossible to get a raw websocket stream from WCF?

Testing with [wsdump](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/master/bin/wsdump.py) like this

```
$ wsdump.py ws://10.0.83.14/WsTest/Ws
Handshake status 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: [*WebSockets will be used when the NetHttpBinding determines the service contract defines a callback contract.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-wcf-service-that-communicates-over-websockets) but I don't see a callback contract in your code, right? Then I still wonder how that callback should work with a stream but it was worth pointing this out first.